# Message box to include textbox.text 

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show the textbox text in my message box keep getting error.

```
MessageBox.Show(textBox1.text + "Saved As PDF");
```

and the error is

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for
   'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type
   'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using 
   directive or an assembly reference?) 
   R:\Engineer\Russell Saari\CONFIGURATOR MODELS\MLD028 Userform (C# Coding)\WindowsFormsApplication2\MLD028D Actuator Form Complete.cs 118 38 WindowsFormsApplication
```

Comment: See Brandon's answer. You should have included this in your question. Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7325662/edit) link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Properties usually start with a capital letter.

Try

```
MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + "Saved As PDF");
```

(note the `T` in `.Text` is capitalized)

Comment: @Russell, I'm almost certain you're not getting the same error on the same line of code. The error you posted basically says that TextBox doesn't have a property called `text`. Which is correct, it has a property called `Text`. Did you remember to rebuild your project? Can you add a new error message to your question? (as ChrisF said, use the 'edit' link below your question).

Comment: the error message indicates you did not fix the capitalization.  Perhaps you are looking at the wrong one?

Comment: Usually, one does not see compile errors like that because VS auto-recapitalizes all identifiers that it knows the declaration (or definition) for.

Answer (score 4):

You don't say what the error is, but to start, let's make your code compile. `Text` should be capitalized.

`MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + "Saved As PDF");`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string firstVal = textBox1.SelectedText;

        if (listBox1.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Name");
        }
        else
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to remove this name", +firstVal, "Remove Name" 
             , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Text);
                listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).